# How to get data from a select>option with ngValue

Tags: angular

As I said in the title, I can't get any values returned from a form, more specifically a `select>option` input.

I have seen other questions like this, but they are out of date and most of them say that it was a bug. So I'm verifying if it is still a bug and how is it possible to achieve this now.

I have an object returned from Firebase:

```
car: {
  {id: 1, name: 'a'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  {id: 3, name: 'c'}
}
```

This is the HTML code I expected to work:

```
<select #id class = "form-control">
   <option *ngFor = "let car of cars" [ngValue] = "car.key">{{ car.name }}</option>
</select>
```

And resolve in my component:

```
ngOnInit () {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({ 
    id: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

So if I'd `console.log` the value of the `id`, this should return the Id of the selected object, but it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it with object

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="user"/>
    </div>
    <label>Service</label>
    <select name="service" [(ngModel)]="user.service">
        <option *ngFor='let service of services' [ngValue]='service'>{{service.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Create User</button>
</form>
```

I can see you are using Model driven forms, you don't realy need that if you aint gona do unit testing:

[Reference](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol#modeldriven-or-templatedriven)

Here is quick way of defining template driven forms:

User object:

```
import { Service } from './service';
export User{
   name: string,
   service: Service
}
```

User Component:

```
export class UserComponent  implements OnInit{
    user = User;
    services = [{...},{...}];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = <User>{}; // Initialize empty object, type assertion, with this we loose type safety
    }
    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.user); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to add a form control to your select field. Would look like:

```
<select [formControl]="id" class="form-control">
```

The template reference variable will let you access that DOM element from your Component, but won't work for forms.

I'd recommend reading http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/ for more information.

Edit: I noticed you've got the form builder group in ngOnInit. Unless you need the formBuilder within ngOnInit, I'd recommend moving it to your constructor.

Comment: `FormBuilder` in `ngOnInit()` should work fine in Angular2 final (added support to change the form reference after first binding). It's usually good practice to not have any code in the constructor if there is no specific need to put it there. Less code in the constructor usually makes a class easier to test.

Comment: Didn't realize they added that into final. Please ignore my comment above then.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `#id` you need `name="id"`

```
<select name="id" class = "form-control">
```

for formbuilder to be able to make the connection.

Comment: This does not work, I tried every combination. Have you test this out?

Comment: No, I haven't tested it. Can you create a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready to use Angular2 template. Then I can have another look.

Comment: Does not work either. Have you tested this out? Very nice documentation, ng-book, but it hadn't the answers I'm looking for =(.

Comment: I don't know what is happening. Looks like I need to import something, I'm new in Plunkr and I don't know how it's done. Anyway, here is the plunkr: [link]  (https://plnkr.co/edit/Wafj7CpiuQUXgv0VUgAR?p=preview).

Comment: The new button provides an Angular2 (new > Angular > 2.0 (TS) ) template. Use this template and add from there.